# Menu interaction with php

Tags: php, jquery, css, database, menu

need an advice regarding a menu interconnectio with my php page.
if I have 3 different div. I would like to place the menu in the first one and load content in the second and third div depending on the voice of the menu that i click.
More clearly if I have a menu with 4 choice and I click on the first one, I would like to load some content in the second and third div.
When I click on the second voice of the menu, I would like this content to change with something else.
So basically update the content of the div 2 and 3 depending of the menu voice.

Can I for exemple store the content in the database and use mysql to load the contents? or jquery? dont know... any suggestion?

In the specifix I want to make communicate the div left with the right and the footer

```
<div id="container">

        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="nav">
         <div>
            <?php
            date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
             echo " Italy time: " . date("h:i:sa");
             echo " day " . date("d/m/Y") . "<br>";
              ?>
        </div>
         <div>
            <?php
            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Vientiane");
            echo "Vietnam time " . date("h:i:sa");
               echo " day " . date("d/m/Y") . "<br>";
             ?>
       </div>
     </div>
        <div id="main">
              <div  id="main_left">Global Trip Schedule</div>

            <div id="main_right">Map Trip Schedule</div>
 </div>
         <div id="footer"></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Please included the Code you are asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but it's too long for a comment: yes you can absolutely do something like this, and there are a few ways to do this.  Your biggest challenge is going to be how you handle the global memory space, by which I mean what each div knows about every other div.

This could be done without PHP at all using only JavaScript and input fields (checkboxes, popups, etc.).  Or if you need it to be filled with dynamic data then you'll have to go back and forth between PHP and the HTML DOM.

I'm going to be honest in telling you before someone else does that StackOverflow is not really meant to be used to ask very introductory "How do I?" type questions and most likely an administrator is going to come along and close this question for that very reason.  So what I would suggest is that you do a Google search for some introductory sites or tutorials that might more specifically answer your question.  You might also want to look into some MVC templates like Laravel or others that are built to do this exact thing.  Good luck!